# In paypal return url $_REQUEST not Getting PhoneNumber(i.e., night_phone_a, night_phone_b, night_phone_c) html field value

Tags: paypal

In paypal return url `$_REQUEST` not Getting the value of PhoneNumber(i.e., night_phone_a, night_phone_b, night_phone_c) html field value.

The fields in paypal form:

```
`<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="732">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">`
```

But in return_url under $_REQUEST i'm not getting  phone value.

Comment: suggestion:  try Eric Lawrence's Fiddler to determine exactly what you're sending and what you're getting back.  [www.telerik.com/fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Is this IPN? Some other Paypal API?

Comment: it is IPN not other API's